# Verilog array assignments

Tags: windows, verilog

```
module sobel_CI(a,result,clock);

input clock;
input [31:0] a[0:3];

output [31:0] result;
assign result= a[0]+a[1]+a[2]+a[3];
endmodule
```

I'm trying to do array declaration in Verilog but it is showing an error:

> function argument with unpacked array required systemverilog extensions.

What is wrong with my array?

Answer (score 5):

In Verilog,You can not use multidimensional entity as an input or output, It is allowed in SystemVerilog.

> Verilog doesn't allow an I/O port to be a 2-D array.

In Verilog 2001 you could flatten your array into a vector and pass that through the port, but that's somewhat awkward. Here is one way to do it:

```
module top (in, out);
input   [31:0] in; 
wire     [7:0] array [0:3];
output  [31:0] out;

assign {array[3],array[2],array[1],array[0]} = in;
assign out = {array[3],array[2],array[1],array[0]};
endmodule
```

Comment: Also, unless you really have a good reason not to, I suggest using SystemVerilog. The Verilog language turned into SystemVerilog 11 years ago. The work-around in this answer is the only way to do it in Verilog, but it is awkward and prone to typo induced bugs that are hard to find.